# responsive design not work properly on iphone 4 and 5

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why this part of my landingpage is jumping around. It is only on Iphone 4 and 5. Anything else is looking fine.

[image: Responsive design]

Maybe it is hard to say out from this code, but could anybody have an idea what is going wrong here?

I would say that the relevant code is what I post here. It is the one there is styling the mobile design:

I use the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <div class="action fullscreen parallax" style="background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <h2>PROGRAM FOR DAGEN</h2>
                        <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline">
                            <li>
                                <time class="cbp_tmtime"><span>08:00 08:15</span></time>
                                <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone"></div>
                                <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
                                    <h2>Velkomst & Lækker morgenmads buffet</h2>

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <time class="cbp_tmtime"><span>08:15 08:45</span></time>
                                <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-screen"></div>
                                <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
                                    <h2>Fremtidens effektive salgsorganisation</h2>

                                    <p>Some text
salgsorganisation skal indrettes.</p>
                                </div>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Responsive Design */
    @media screen and (max-width: 65.375em) {

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 47.2em) {
        .cbp_tmtimeline:before {
            display: none;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 0 20px 0;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel {
            margin: 0 0 30px 0;
            padding: 1em;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 95%;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel:after {
            right: auto;
            left: 20px;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: #3594cb;
            top: -20px;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: #6cbfee;
        }

        .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmicon {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            left: auto;
            margin: -55px 5px 0 0px;
        }
```

Comment: Paste some html for us, please.

Comment: What meta viewport value are you using?

Comment: Thank you a lot to both of you for your answers. I just updated my question, so I hope you can see what is wrong?